# API json postman and drupal 8

Tags: php, json, api, postman, drupal-8

How are you my friends ?

i have an issue with API with drupal 8 in post method

when i send the request the respond is 406 Not Acceptable

this is the code

```
POST /movies/entity/node?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1
Host: abdallah.tech
X-CSRF-Token: t1UOL3VNN0GRGSNxWN************************
Authorization: Basic ************************
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 4f61c400-4916-4dfb-8ca7-0ed08c48a4bc

    {
  "_links": {
    "type": {
      "href": "http://abdallah.tech:8083/movies/rest/node/add/movies"
    }
  },
  "type": [{
      "target_id": "movies"
    }],
  "title": [{
      "value": "hello world"
    }],
  "body": [{
      "value": "some body content aaa bbb ccc"
  }]

}'
```

can you help me with that please

Answer (score 2):

just try to change

```
POST /movies/entity/node?_format=hal_json HTTP/1.1
```

to

```
POST /movies/node?_format=hal_json
// or
POST /node?_format=hal_json
```